# Akka: ActorRef is resolved but the messages are sent to an other actor (its child)

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I get an actorRef like this:

```
context
  .actorSelection(sender.path.parent)
  .resolveOne()
  .map { actorRef =>
     println("selfSender = " + self.path)
     println("actorRefOfReceiverInSender = " + actorRef)
     actorRef ! MyMessage()
 }
```

It outputs (I'm sure there is no other logs in the application):

```
selfSender = akka://application/user/get-facebook-event
actorRefReceiverInSender = Actor[akka://application/user/events-by-place-supervisor#105204402]
```

So all seems OK.

The problem is that the messages are not received in the correct actor: `events-by-place-supervisor` (found by the `resolveOne` methods) but in its child as showing by the following logs from the child:

```
selfChild = akka://application/user/events-by-place-supervisor/get-events-by-places
senderInChild = Actor[akka://application/user/get-facebook-event#1400767854]
```

So it comes from the good sender, but the receiver is not the one found by the `resolveOne` method but its child.
How can it be possible that `actorRef ! MyMessage()` does not send the message to the good actor referenced by `actorRef`?

Comment: Can you paste the complete actor creation, message send, and also the MyMessage() code pieces. There too few info that can't figure out the root cause.